# Фильтр записей в таблице

Tags: php, javascript

На странице есть что-то типо таблицы, куда попадают записи из БД с помощью аякс запроса при загрузке этой самой страницы. Также есть кнопки, 1D 1W 1M. Как мне фильтровать отображение записей, при нажатии этих кнопок, т.е чтобы если я нажал 1D - остались только записи сделанные за этот день и тд. В БД время хранится в виде чисел, например 1535149828 или 1535149959. А вставляются в таблицу уже так:

```
var OrdTime = new Date(result.Active_Orders_User.TimeCreateOrders[i]*1000);
                                OrdYear=addZero(OrdTime.getFullYear());
                                OrdMonth=addZero(OrdTime.getMonth()+1);
                                OrdDay=addZero(OrdTime.getDate());
                                OrdHour=addZero(OrdTime.getHours());
                                OrdMin=addZero(OrdTime.getMinutes());
                                OrdSec=addZero(OrdTime.getSeconds());

     '<div class="my__table-t">' +OrdYear+'.'+OrdMonth+'.'+OrdDay+' <span>'+OrdHour+':'+OrdMin+':'+OrdSec+ '</span></div>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Наилучший вариант фильтрации через sql запрос -

```
SELECT * FROM tableNAME WHERE DATE(created_at) > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

Но можно и через js -

```
var now = new Date()
now.setDate(now.getDate() + 3)
arr.filter(item => item.date > +now);
```